# Create new UINSWindow from Catalyst

Tags: swift, appkit, mac-catalyst

In my Catalyst app I'm creating a second window using the following code:

```
let userActivity = NSUserActivity(activityType: "window2")
UIApplication.shared.requestSceneSessionActivation(nil, userActivity: userActivity, options: nil) { error in
    print("error: \(error)")
}
```

This creates a new window, but it's of type `NSPopoverWindow` and not `UINSWindow` as I expected.

I need to change the properties of the underlying NSWindow object and I have create a MacOS Bundle to interface AppKit as described in this fine blogpost:
[Mac Catalyst: Interfacing Between UIKit and AppKit without Private APIs in Swift](https://philzet.medium.com/mac-catalyst-interfacing-between-uikit-and-appkit-without-private-apis-in-swift-5d6b90dab08d)

So, is it possible to create a new `UINSWindow` from Catalyst, or do I need to create it with AppKit from my MacOS Bundle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like both a new `NSPopoverWindow` and a new `UINSWindow` are created when the new scene is activated, and both are added to the `NSApplication.sharedApplication.windows` array. As `NSPopoverWindow` doesn't have an `uiWindows` property, the code from the blogpost crashed.
Checking the object type solved my problem:

```
private func nsWindow(from window: UIWindow) -> AnyObject? {
    guard let nsWindows = NSClassFromString("NSApplication")?.value(forKeyPath: "sharedApplication.windows") as? [AnyObject] else { return nil }
    for nsWindow in nsWindows {
        if !String(describing: nsWindow).contains("UINSWindow") {
            continue
        }
        
        let uiWindows = nsWindow.value(forKeyPath: "uiWindows") as? [UIWindow] ?? []
        if uiWindows.contains(window) {
            return nsWindow
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```